# Creating new ultragrid from old ultragrid by applying filter on cell of old grid in C# win form

Tags: c#, winforms, ultrawingrid

I have to create new ultagrid from a given ultragrid which have filter value of old ultragrid for example:- I have a ultragrid(XYZ) which hava A,B,C column & i have to create a new grid from this grid by applying the condition that if C cloumn do not have any value in cell then dont add that entire row to the new grid.

I tried nested loop but it does not work.